# Google Sheets- How to Clear, Zero Out, or Replace Specific Cells Efficiently Via Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is three similar actions needed in one sheet. Hopefully this ends up being a useful question in general.

I have a script that copies the values of arbitrary cells on a sheet to a single row in another sheet, courtesy of doubleunary's answer to a prior question. Now I need to know how to reset the input sheet to be ready for another entry.

Some cells need to be blank, some need to be zeroes, and some need to be reset to a default text value, which is stored on another sheet so it can be changed easily if needed.

The script for pulling the data is this:

```js
function submitDataOhSoMuchFaster() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const values = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:Z13').getValues();
  const entry = [
    { column: 26, row: 12 }, // Z12
    { column: 3, row: 2 }, // C2
    { column: 14, row: 2 }, // N2
    { column: 3, row: 10 }, // C10
    { column: 6, row: 2 }, // F2
    { column: 3, row: 4 }, // C4
    { column: 5, row: 4 }, // E4
    { column: 3, row: 5 }, // C5
    { column: 5, row: 5 }, // E5
    { column: 12, row: 5 }, // L5
    { column: 12, row: 4 }, // L4
    { column: 26, row: 13 }, // Z13
    { column: 20, row: 4 }, // T4
    { column: 20, row: 5 }, // T5
    { column: 3, row: 6 }, // C6
  ];
  ss.getSheetByName('Master Log')
    .appendRow(entry.map(cell => values[cell.row - 1][cell.column - 1]));
};
```

I want to know if there is a way to elegantly reverse that, and either clear or write zeroes to a set of cells or ranges using a similar method, and how I would efficiently go about writing the values of a small array on a source sheet to arbitrary cells on the target sheet.

As examples, I need to:

Clear C4, E4, J10:J14, etc.

Zero T5:T6, D12:D15

Copy the contents of cell AT2 on one sheet to F2 on the target sheet, AT3 to C10, etc. (all the source data for this is in a single column, so an array seems workable)

I know how to do this in a lengthy manner that uses a ton of Clear, getValue and setValue commands, but how do I do it efficiently?

Edit:

The source range for the third step is here:

[image: Source Range for default entries]

And the targets are here:

[image: Target sheet for default entries]

Comment: I can understand your 1st and 2nd requests of `Clear C4, E4, J10:J14, etc.` and `Zero T5:T6, D12:D15`. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your 3rd request of `Copy the contents of cell AT2 on one sheet to F2 on the target sheet, AT3 to C10, etc. (all the source data for this is in a single column, so an array seems workable)`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image?

Comment: Added. Thank you for your interest in the question!

Comment: Honestly, a better method may be to use a template. Do what you need to with your input sheet, then replace it with a **copy** of the template each time you need a refresh.

Comment: I would be up for that. I can just make a sheet that is the "clean" version and copy it over? How would I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution:

The most elegant way I can think of is using [RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list):

- [RangeList.setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list) sets the value of all cells in all specified ranges at once.
- [RangeList.getRanges](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list) gets an array with the ranges, and you can then set the new values in a loop.

#### Code snippet:

```
function updateSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("TARGET");
  targetSheet.getRangeList(["C4","E4","J10:J14"]).setValue("");  
  targetSheet.getRangeList(["T5:T6", "D12:D15"]).setValue(0);
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SOURCE");
  const values = sourceSheet.getRange("AT2:AT" + sourceSheet.getLastRow())
                            .getValues().flat();
  targetSheet.getRangeList(["F2","C10",...]).getRanges()
             .forEach((range,i) => range.setValue(values[i]));
}
```